# Build an input dialog box?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I understand that there is no default input dialog in silverlight for windows phone 7. But i need this for my project.

I want it to have the same metro look as the default messagebox class. Whats the easiest way to do this? Can i extend the messagebox class and add som kind of textfield to it? Or should i perhaps use popup or child window?

Please help my out on this one guys :) Stack overflow has been a great asset and has helped me alot when I get stuck in my projects!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [InputPrompt](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=InputPrompt) from the [Coding4Fun Toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/):

```
InputPrompt prompt = new InputPrompt();
prompt.Title = "Here Is A Title";
prompt.Message = "Specify a unique message:";
prompt.Show();

prompt.Completed += (pResult,sResult) =>
    {
    }
```

Or you could use the `CustomMessageBox` from [WPToolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/):

```
CustomMessageBox box = new CustomMessageBox()
{
    Caption = "Your Caption Here",
    Message = "Enter a unique message",
    LeftButtonContent = "ok",
    RightButtonContent = "cancel",
    Content = textBox    
};

box.Dismissed += (s, boxEventArgs) =>
    {
    }

box.Show();
```

Both are great options and at the end of the day it will be a matter of preference as to which one to use for your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

I used to see a NotificationMessageBox; I'm not use if it works. If there is really no existing control to use, I would rather use Popup to make my custom dialog. You can use text box there. :)

Answer (score 0):

I published a blog post about [Customizing MessageBox on Windows Phone 7](http://cloudstore.blogspot.com/2011/01/customizing-messagebox-on-windows-phone.html), which might help. Another alternative woudl be to use the `InputPrompt` from the [Coding4Fun Toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

use messagePrompt from Coding4FunToolkit for WP...

you can do it like this:

```
MessagePrompt p = new MessagePrompt();
p.Body = (any UserControl(customized), string, etc.)
p.Show();
```